# CSS button won't align correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Attached is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWake.png) I have the following CSS. I want the button to align perfectly at the center of the nav and towards the left. However, currently I cannot figure out a way to get the button aligned properly and to continue functioning. I want to achieve the same thing done on https://house.jumia.com.ng/ Any help would be appreciated! Here's my code:

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #36b;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.first {
  border-color: #73ADFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #73ADFF;
  vertical-align: middle, !important;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn first"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button></a>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain more "at the center of the nav and towards the left"? And maybe you want it like that because you will add another button next to it, is that right?

Comment: Vertical alignment? 


In .first add margin-top: 14px;

Your nav is 68px and your button is 40px so it's 28/2 on top and bottom of it to make it vertically centered.

Comment: When referring to alignment with `css` it's important to distinguish between **vertical** and **horizontal** alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Due to the bootstrap framework, the snippet showing here is different from what I have on my screen. Attached is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSWCT.png) Thanks to everyone that reached out to me. I made a little adjustment to my css, and I have achieved what I was trying to achieve. Here's the code:

```css
.navbar-custom {
            background-color:#36b;
            color:#ffffff;
            border-radius:0;
   height:68px;
   margin-bottom: 0;
            }
   
   .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
       padding-left: 0;
       padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
       font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
       font-weight:300;
       font-size:13px;
   }
  
    .first {
  border-color: #73ADFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color:#73ADFF;
  vertical-align:middle,!important;
      padding: 10px 16px;
   line-height: 16px;
       display: inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-top:14px;
    margin-right:100px;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
                 <div class="container">
                                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
                          <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn first"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button></a>
                            </ul>
                       </div>
                  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this easy code:

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #36b;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}

.first {
border-color: #73ADFF;
color: #fff;
background-color: #73ADFF;
padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn first"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button></a>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-custom {
                background-color:#36b;
                color:#ffffff;
                border-radius:0;
       height:68px;
       margin-bottom: 0;
                }

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
       padding-left: 0;
       padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
       font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
       font-weight:300;
       font-size:13px;
   }

        .first {
      border-color: #73ADFF;
      color: #fff;
      background-color:#73ADFF;
      vertical-align:middle,!important;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      line-height: 16px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size:12px;
      font-weight:600;
    }
    .ulClass{
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:0px

    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
      <div class="container">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ulClass">  
              <a href="signup.php">
              <button class="btn first">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it's not centered

Comment: You may also consider adding some explanatin, a "code-only" answer isn't very good as the OP may not understand what you did ;)

Comment: sorry i added the ul a class named: ulClass and in the css i added:

`.ulClass{
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:0px

    }`

Comment: I know what you did, it's not for me ... it's for everyone that will see your answer. I am experienced so i can understand by seeing the code by it's not the case of everyone.

Comment: I'm going to upload a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align: center;` to the parent class `.navbar-custom`. Here's the working code snippet:

```html
<html>
    <style>
        .navbar-custom {
            background-color: #36b;
            color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 0;
            height: 68px;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            text-align:center;
        }
    
        .first {
            border-color: #73ADFF;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #73ADFF;
            vertical-align: middle, !important; /* you have a typo here*/
            padding: 10px 16px;
            line-height: 16px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <a href="signup.php">
                    <button class="btn first">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button>
                </a>
            </ul>
    
        </div>
    </nav>
</html>
```

Comment: consider adding a snippet code so we can see the result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Check the  // comment

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #36b;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  
  text-align: center; // center horizontally
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.nav {
  padding: 0; // clear margin + padding of the <ul>
  margin: 0;
}

.first {
  border-color: #73ADFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #73ADFF;
  vertical-align: middle, !important;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  
  margin: 14px 0; // center vertically
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <a href="signup.php">
        <button class="btn first"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to center the content of the navbar-custom,

**just add :**

```
.navbar-custom {
  display: flex;
  /* Center vertically */
  align-items: center;
  /* Center horizontally */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Don't forget to remove **default list style** :

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-custom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #36b;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.first {
  border-color: #73ADFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #73ADFF;
  vertical-align: middle, !important;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn first"><span 
        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER 
        PROPERTY</button></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `<li>` element missing in `<ul>`.
Only `<li>` items allowed as a direct child of `<ul>`.

Plus your button isn't aligned to center, you can do it inside the `<ul>`:

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #36b;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 68px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 75px 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.first {
  border-color: #73ADFF;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #73ADFF;
  vertical-align: middle, !important;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn first"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;OFFER PROPERTY</button></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```